# How can count outlier and inlier points after applying RANSAC?

Tags: opencv, matching, ransac

I have gone through the code below and would like to know how can I count the outlier points and inlier points after using RANSAC? could you point to a good code how it can be done?

Second question, which feature matching algorithm is better: BFMatcher.knnMatch() with Test ratio or bf = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True) with shortest distance? any reference for this comparison?

```
    **# BFMatcher with default params
      bf = cv.BFMatcher()
      matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

     # Apply ratio test
     good_matches = []
     for m,n in matches:
         if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
           good_matches.append([m])
        
       # Draw matches
   img3=cv.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good_matches,None,flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
     cv.imwrite('matches.jpg', img3)
     # Select good matched keypoints
     ref_matched_kpts = np.float32([kp1[m[0].queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches])
     sensed_matched_kpts = np.float32([kp2[m[0].trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches])

     # Compute homography
     H, status = cv.findHomography(sensed_matched_kpts, ref_matched_kpts, cv.RANSAC,5.0)**
```

Answer (score 0):

**Count number of outliers and inliers**

```
# number of detected outliers: len(status) - np.sum(status)
# number of detected inliers: np.sum(status)
# Inlier Ratio, number of inlier/number of matches: float(np.sum(status)) / float(len(status))
```

**Feature Matching Algorithm**

I would say that if you are using the sparse feature-based algorithm (SIFT or SURF), `BFMatcher.knnMatch() with Test ratio` is preferred. While the `bf = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)` is used for binary-based algorithm (ORB, FAST, etc). My suggestion would be try both algorithms on your project to investigate which one is better.